# Запись в чужой кадр стека

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, стек

Получил интересную проблему. У меня есть функция `void F()`, то есть не принимает никаких параметров. Но в её ассемблерном коде такое начало:

```
1: mov rax, rsp
2: mov qword ptr [rax+8], rbx
3: push rdi
...
```

Я удивлен второй строке. Если мы не передаем параметров, почему функция позволяет себе перезаписать значение `[rsp+8]`. По адресу `[rsp]` содержится адрес возврата, но далее ведь уже чужой кадр стека, а эта функция перезаписывает значение. В дальнейшем из-за этого у меня возникает ошибка. Почему присутствует такая команда и что можно сделать?

Добавлю, что это учебное задание и в рамках его я формирую стек вручную (записываю адреса возврата, параметры функций и т.п.). В *Debug*-версии все нормально, в *Release* вот в этом месте перезаписывается нужное мне значение.

Comment: Вы бы C-код этой функции привели и полное asm начало. может это ваша собственная операция, вы же что то делаете как раз со стеком

Comment: @Mike эта функция написана полностью на С++, со стеком я в ней напрямую не работаю, то есть испортить ничего не мог.

Comment: Я что то не совсем понял. Вот эта приведенная вами первая строчка кода и есть самое начало функции. Там более не было ни одной инструкции, какого нибудь enter, например. Просто это абсолютно не похоже на стандартные начала которые генерят компиляторы для функций

Comment: @Mike это реально сделано компилятором

Comment: Я понял что компилятором. как вы определили, что это первые инструкции функции. Компиляторы начинают либо с `enter` либо с `push rbp`

Comment: @Mike, ну я в отладчике проходил, попал на эту строчку.

Comment: Ассемблерный исходник лучше выдавите из компилятора. Для `gcc` это ключ `-S`.

Comment: @PinkTux а как в студии это сделать?

Comment: В отладчике какого уровня. он по C-коду шел или по инструкциям asm. эти строки запросто могут быть первой C-шной строкой внутри функции, а преамбулу отладчик мог и не показывать. А в преамбуле обычно самая соль, там rsp уменьшается на размер локальных переменных функции, после чего подобные строки - это работа с локальными переменными

Comment: @Mike там далее есть `sub rsp, 60h`

Comment: далее не может быть. т.е. может - но это уже дложна быть другая функция. sub rsp обычно третья инструкция функции

Comment: @АлексейСаровский `/Fa` даст вам исходник на ассемблере.

Comment: Такой код похож на сохранение регистра, в котором передавался параметр `this` при вызове метода класса. Ваше `void F()` - это часом   не метод класса? Однако `this` обычно передается в `rcx`...